# Bit.dev how to create scss component?

Tags: reactjs, sass, bit.dev

I tried to create a bit.dev scss. I am using this command and it's not working.
`bit create scss variables/colors`

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I found the solution. I had to create a html-env.
I did this `bit create html-env envs/my-html-env` and it worked after that.